# What is the best microphone type for recording natural outdoor sounds?

Tags: sound-design, microphone, sound-effects, field-recording, design

I am currently working on a game, and I wanted to take on the challenge to record the sounds myself. I will need a lot of outdoor natural sounds, like flowing water, trees in wind or footsteps on dirt.

What would be the best microphone type I could use? From my research I’ve learned that Large Diaphragm Condenser microphone should be best because of their low noise. Would you agree with that?

Should I go for stereo?

And would you have any specific recommendations? I don’t have a lot of money and think I shouldn’t spend more than 100€.

Here is the one I’m considering to buy:
https://www.lyxpro.com/products/lyxldc20-lyxpro-ldc-20-large-diaphragm-cardioid-condenser-studio-microphone-shockmount-foam-windscreen-case

Answer (score 2):

What is needed for recording outdoor sounds:

- a high sensitivity low noise microphone
- a windjammer, shock-mount, stand or boompole
- a field recorder with low noise mic preamp

If you want to make stereo recordings (or record simultaneously several *point of hearing*), that's two microphones and accessories kits.

Unfortunately, buying this kind of gear for less than 100 € is currently not possible.

Large diaphragm microphones are not the most common choice for this task because they are usually not conceived to be put into a windjammer and a boompole. They might also be less resilient to outdoor conditions (temperature, humidity, ...).

You should also take into consideration that, depending on your location, finding a place to record natural outdoor sound without being subject to undesirable sounds (roads, trains, planes, human activity, animal activity, ...) might be challenging.

Comment: I’m fortunate to live very near to a few mountains. Background noise shouldn’t be a problem. What would be a sensitive low noise microphone?